# Deleting Firestore documents with firebase-tools is not working

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am calling a cloud function from iOS to delete documents in Firestore. The function gets called and executes but the actual deletion never happens. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Cloud Function:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const firebase_tools = require('firebase-tools');

exports.recursiveDelete = functions
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    memory: '2GB'
  })
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const path = data.path;
    console.log(
      `User ${context.auth.uid} has requested to delete path ${path}`
    );

    return firebase_tools.firestore
      .delete(path, {
        project: process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT,
        recursive: true,
        yes: true,
        token: functions.config().fb.token
      })
      .then(() => {
        return {
          path: path
        };
      });
  });
```

**iOS**

```
let deleteFunction = functions.httpsCallable("recursiveDelete")
        deleteFunction.call(["path": docPath]) { (result, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
                    let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
                    let message = error.localizedDescription
                    let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
                    print("\(code): \(message)\n\nDetails: \(details)")
                }
            } else {
                print("Deletion was successful")
            }
        }
```

**Here is the console output from Xcode:**

```
Optional(__C.FIRFunctionsErrorCode): INTERNAL

Details: nil
```

**Here is the log from the execution:**
[image]

Comment: At first glance your code looks fine. Are you sure you're checking the right document? If so: can you try reproducing this by running a local Node.js script, instead of Cloud Functions? That would significantly simplify the setup, making it easier to focus on what's going on, and to reproduce.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, I'm sure it's the right document. In the function execution log,  the document path is what I expect.

Comment: It would help to know `docPath`, right?

Answer (score 2):

Try to check version of NodeJS. In NodeJS 10 and up, lot of environment variables were removed, including `process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT`, which now returns `undefined`.

Instead of `process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT`, you have several options:

Hardcode your project ID as a string:

```
.delete(path, {
        project: "myprojectid-12345",
        recursive: true,
        yes: true,
        token: functions.config().fb.token
      })
```

You can also pick up your project ID from firebase config:

`myProjectID = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId`

Please note, as stated [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/437#issuecomment-701474857):

> FIREBASE_CONFIG is always populated by the Firebase CLI when
> deploying, but will not be present when deploying via gcloud or other
> means.

Or based on [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/migrating/nodejs-runtimes) setup your own environment variable when deploying your function.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. For my Cloud NodeJS 14 runtime, the process.env.GCP_PROJECT is somehow undefined